# Generate unique token with creation time inside

Tags: java, java-8, token, access-token

Only using java 8, with no other libraries, I need to generate a unique token which expires in 5 minutes, but instead of saving the creation time on DB, I would like to store the creation time inside the token to decode it later when it used.

How could I do it?

Comment: Take the creation time and add a MAC to it so that it cannot easily be changed. This will however not be unique if you issue more than one token per millisecond. If you need that you can add a counter value.

Comment: This seems to be a conceptual problem rather than a programming problem. You can get the creation time via `System.currentTimeMillis()`. What you do with that `long` depends on the nature of your token and what kind of security you need. Or how you validate the correctness of a token. I guess, there still *has* to be a database storage, hasn’t it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer of you question

```
String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ":" + System.currentTimeMillis();
String[] t = token.split(":");
String token_time = t[1];
```

Then you can do what ever you want with the `token_time` variable
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate a token composed of two parts that are concatenated:

1. the first part a UUID to be sure the token is unique; [UUID reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)
2. the second part a timestamp that you can decode later

Comment: Could use V1 of the UUID spec, contains the timestamp already! ;)

Comment: Sounds simple, but how do you verify the correctness of the token? If you do so by storing the complete token, you have effectively stored the time, which the OP wants to avoid.